# Can I define a function with '#'-namespace in a file with hyphen '-' in its name?

Tags: vimscript, functions, filenames

I often see #-namespaces in plugins source code, e.g `coc#status(), fzf#run(), fugitive#extract_git_dir`. I would like to use namespaces in my own config, mappings and commands source code also. But I'm getting errors `E746: Function name does not match script file name` so it turns out that namespace must match the name of the file where the function is defined. But file names may have hyphen while function names can't. So how can I define function with namespace in a file `foo-bar.vim`? Is it possible?

Comment: That `#` is not a namespace as in other general purposed programming langs. It indicates function is `autoloaded`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> So how can I define function with namespace in a file foo-bar.vim? Is it possible?

I don't think it is possible.

See `:h 41.15` of the User Manual for `autoload` feature of vim (which you call namespace)

```
When such a function is called, and it is not defined yet, Vim will search the
"autoload" directories in 'runtimepath' for a script file called
"filename.vim".  For example "~/.vim/autoload/filename.vim".  That file should
then define the function like this: >

    function filename#funcname()
       echo "Done!"
    endfunction

The file name and the name used before the # in the function must match
exactly, and the defined function must have the name exactly as it will be
called.
```

**Fact 1:**

The file name and the name used before the # in the function must match
exactly

**Fact 2:**

Minus `-` is a binary operation in vimscript -- `test-me#hello()` is considered as `test` variable minus `me` variable.

**Resolution**

Do not use dashes in the names of your autoloaded files.

Comment: There's an exception in that a `namespace#...` function *can* be defined in a `plugin/` file (not only in an `autoload/` one), but even then, I believe the file name must match `namespace.vim`. An example is if which defines some functions [here](https://github.com/junegunn/fzf/blob/0.27.2/plugin/fzf.vim#L447). Note that this is pretty confusing, since one who's debugging it and looking for these functions will go to `autoload/` and be befuddled by them not being there... So it's not a practice I would recommend anyways.